# How to get the week number by the model's time in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic, week-number

How can I get the week number of the year by the model's time in Anylogic?

Thank for your help!

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `time(WEEK)`

Returns the current model time in weeks.

If you need the relative week number of a year (0-51), you can use `getDayOfYear(date()) / 52.` and then round it how you like. `getDayOfYear` gives the relative day of a year for the current model time (0-364)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it. I just didn't find the `time(WEEK)` function in the Anylogic help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that returns the week number by the model's time (if the week starts on Monday):

```
int weekNumber = 1;
int dayOfWeekNewYear = 1;
if (getDayOfWeek(toDate(getYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)) == 1) {
    dayOfWeekNewYear = 7;
}
else {
    dayOfWeekNewYear = getDayOfWeek(toDate(getYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)) - 1;
}
if (dayOfWeekNewYear <= 4) {
    weekNumber = (int)Math.ceil((double)(getDayOfYear(date()) + (dayOfWeekNewYear - 1))/7);
}
else {
    if ((getDayOfYear(date()) - (8 - dayOfWeekNewYear)) > 0) {
        weekNumber = (int)Math.ceil((double)(getDayOfYear(date()) - (8 - dayOfWeekNewYear))/7);
    }
    else {
        weekNumber = 52;
    }
}
```